# __WFI() will not sleep even with all interrupts disabled and pending cleared - LPC18XX Series

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt, cortex-m, lpc

Background: I am trying to make my embedded application go to sleep when there is no CAN activity with the __WFI() and then wake up whenever a CAN interrupt is received. Before enterring sleep mode, I disable all interrupts and clear their pending states in the NVIC registers.

**To start, right now I'm just trying to make sure that I can sleep forever when I have all interrupts disabled.**

```
for(int i = 0; i < IRQ_MAX; i++)
{
    IRQ_ClearPending((IRQ)i);
    IRQ_Disable((IRQ)i);
}
__DSB();
__ISB();
__WFI();

MCU_Reset();
```

I checked the NVIC registers, and they are all set to 0, which should mean that all interrupts are disabled and there are no pending interrupts. However, everytime I execture the WFI (Wait for interrupt) instruction, it will just NOP on me.

Why can I not enter sleep mode? Do I actually have to somehow disable all of my peripherals and disable the interrupts at their source or is there a way to just mask all interrupts minus the CAN?

Thank you for your time. Let me know if there is anything I can do to clarify the question.

Comment: Are you stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: @FiddlingBits yes, but I have tried with the debugger disconnected as well and it is the same behavior.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because the debugger may be preventing the device from sleeping.

Comment: This code won't  disable `SysTick`, because that does not go through the `NVIC` at all.

Comment: @TurboJ that could expain it. I know for sure that SysTick is still being used by the RTOS, but I thought that the WFI instruction only pertained to NVIC interrupts.I will try and see what it would take to disable the SysTick and if that works.

Comment: "The WFI instruction can complete even if no exception becomes active. Do not use it to detect the occurrence of an exception."

Comment: "ARM recommends that software always uses the WFI instruction in a loop, and does not assume that the
processor either enters low-power state, or remains in low-power state, after any particular execution of the
WFI instruction."

Comment: What if you have an interrupt enabled does it still nop?  and this is a cortex-m3 not one of the cores where the WFI is actually a nop?

Answer (score -1):

Check for imprecise external abort, which does not cause exception immediately.

Comment: This is a rather terse answer.